# Subnetting - Networking

Tags: networking, ip-address

How to find the **network address** of a particular LAN with a given ip address and a subnet mask of a host in that network?
As an example if the ip address of the host is 192.168.1.1 and the subnet mask is 255.255.255.128, what would be the network address that it belongs?

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains it all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the AND operation, and to do that first you need to convert both the IP address and the subnet mask to their binary equivalent. The rule of AND operation is given below: 
`0 AND 0 = 0` 
`0 AND 1 = 0` 
`1 AND 0 = 0` 
`1 AND 1 = 1`

Therefore, by using the above rules, we can find the network address of the subnet that a given IP address belongs to:

`192.168.1.1 = 11000000 10101000 00000001 00000001`
`255.255.255.128 = 11111111 11111111 11111111 10000000`

---

`192.168.1.1 = 11000000 10101000 00000001 00000000`

Therefore, the network address is `192.168.1.0`, and the subnet mask is `255.255.255.128`.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. This answer solved my  problem:)

Answer (score 0):

Network address is “192.168.1.0/25”

Host Address Range is “192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.126”

Broadcast Address is “192.168.1.127”

Online subnet calculator is available: https://www.subnet-calculator.com/

You just need to add your IP address and subnet mask as shown below, it will show the required results,

[image]

Or

255.255.255.128 is nothing but /25 so you can simply enter 192.168.1.1/25 in below website to calculate other details:
https://www.site24x7.com/tools/ipv4-subnetcalculator.html

[image]

Subnet calculation concept is explained here,

http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/subnetting-subnet-masks-explained/

Comment: Network classes were deprecated in 1993, two years before the commercial Internet! Anything referencing network classes should be avoided. We have not used network classes in this century.

Comment: @RonMaupin But students need to have basic knowledge about IP addressing. You can't teach them about CIDR if they don't have basic knowledge of IP address classes and subnnetting.

Comment: @HelloWorld You are right! Subnetting plays important role.

Comment: Yes, but not network classes that have not existed for nearly 30 years. Subnetting is essential knowledge, classes are not. I wrote [this two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) to explain it all.

Comment: @RonMaupin You still need to know about classes, so that you can understand number of bits used to represent network/host portions. As a result, you clearly know where you will get the bits you are going to borrow from. If you don't know about classes, then you may not understand where you will borrow the bits to create the sub-nets.

Comment: No, not at all. See the answer I linked. Network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (two years before the commercial Internet) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). We have not used network classes in this century. Learning about network classes is akin to learning that you need to use the crank on a telephone to generate electricity to signal the operator so that you can place a phone call.

Comment: @RonMaupin Of course, I already mentioned about CIDR on my first comment, and it will be even useless in near future when IPv6 replace IPv4. May be it is useless for you (>35 years of experience, respect), but for the new kids you have to start from basic concepts, like: `IP address classes`, `Private & Public address`, `subnetting`, `VLSM` ... then `CIDR`. Remember when we're kids our teachers used to tell us that there are no numbers below 0 (zero)? Just like that, we teach the new fellas about `classes`, and we'll tell them `they are useless` when they are good enough for `CIDR`. Peace.